# boost::regex_replace() replaces only first occurrence, why?

Tags: c++, boost

My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
std::cout << boost::algorithm::replace_regex_copy(
    "{x}{y}", // source string
    boost::regex("\\{.*?\\}"), // what to find
    std::string("{...}") // what to replace to
);
```

This is what I see:

```
{…}{y}
```

Thus, only the first occurrence replaced. Why? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `replace_all_regex_copy()` instead of `replace_regex_copy()`

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression * (zero or more of the previous) operator matches as many characters from the source string as possible, where the *? operator matches as few characters as possible.

So the `.*?` in `boost::regex("\\{.*?\\}")` matches only the `x` in your source string (it wouldn't even do that, except that you've told it to match `}` afterwards) and the entire expression matches `{x}`.

If you actually wanted to match the entire string, you should use `boost::regex("\\{.*\\}")` instead.

Unless you actually wanted to replace both `{x}` and `{y}` with `{...}`, that is ... in which case, please ignore my post. (-: